# Single FancyBox form with multiple links

Tags: php, jquery, fancybox

I am trying to figure out a way to have multiple links and 1 popup FancyBox form.  When a user clicks on one of the countries I would like the country to be selected in my dropdown menu.  Everything is working great except I can't figure out how to select the value in the dropdown.  Can anyone help me with this?  Thank you in advance :).

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

$("a.country-form").fancybox({
        'scrolling' : 'no',
                'titleShow' : false,
                'onClosed'  : function() {
            $("#country_error").hide();
        }       
    });

    $("#country_form").bind("submit", function() {

        if ($("#country_country").val() == 0) {
            $("#country_error").show();
            $.fancybox.resize();
            return false;
        }

        $.fancybox.showActivity();

        $.ajax({
            type    : "POST",
            cache   : false,
            url     : "process.php",
            data    : $("#country_form").serializeArray(),
            success: function(data) {
                $.fancybox(data);
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
}
</script>

<a class="country-form" href="#country_form" >Submit textbook (Canada)</a>
<a class="country-form" href="#country_form" >Submit textbook (United States)</a>
<a class="country-form" href="#country_form" >Submit textbook (United Kingdom)</a>

<div style="display:none">
<form id="country_form" name="country_form" method="post" action="">
<p id="country_error">* There was a problem with your submission.</p>
<h1>Submit textbook in (COUNTRY HERE)</h1>
<label for="country">Country: </label>
<select name="country" id="country_country">
<option value="0">Country...</option>
<option value=1>Canada</option>
<option value=2>United States</option>
<option value=3>United Kingdom</option>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set rel attribute to the link

```
<a class="country-form" rel='1' href="#country_form" >Submit textbook (Canada)</a>
<a class="country-form" rel='2' href="#country_form" >Submit textbook (United States)</a>
<a class="country-form" rel='3' href="#country_form" >Submit textbook (United Kingdom)</a>
```

Then try

```
$("a.country-form").fancybox({
        'scrolling' : 'no',
         'onStart' : function(){
              $("#country_country").val($(this).attr('rel'));
          },
                'titleShow' : false,
                'onClosed'  : function() {
            $("#country_error").hide();
        }       
    });
```

Comment: Exactly.  You beat me to it, @crazyphoton.  You could also use `id` instead of `rel`.  I would also change the selection drop-down values to something meaningful, like `ca`, `us`, and `uk`, instead of 1, 2, and 3.

Comment: yes, id would also work fine! But then, its a bad idea to set id to 1,2 and 3. So it should be something like id="country-form-link-1", id="country-form-link-2" etc. which means you have to parse it to get 1,2 and 3. rel seemed simpler :) and yes, ca us uk might be easier unless the database uses numbers as foreign keys.

Comment: All good points, @crazyphoton.  There's another option, too, which might be better than any of these ideas: using jQuery.data.  Of course that would involve the extra step of setting the appropriate data on the three anchors, but that might actually be a good thing.  Anyway, nice solution!

Comment: Thank you for the help @crazyphoton!!  Got everything working :)